# An elementary fact about Sylow subgroup of Sym(n)

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

Let $\,n\in\mathbb{N}\,$ and $p$ a prime. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\,S_n\,$. If $p$ does not divide $n$, then $\,P\leq S_{n-1}\,$. Why?

Comment: Well, how many times does $p$ divide the order of the group?

Comment: The answer is $p^{[n/p]+[n/p^{2}]+...}$. Here [n/p] denotes the largest integer$\leq$n/p

Comment: Ok, now compare that to the number of times $p$ divides the order of the smaller group.

Comment: It also divides the order of the smaller group.

Comment: The way you have written it, it is not true. *Some* of the p-Sylows are subgroups of $S_{n-1}$.

Comment: @user I recently got scolded about the addition of the abstract algebra tag when a user tags as group theory. I was directed to a meta post on this topic. So I (who has added abstract algebra to many a questions about groups) was just acting on that reprimand.

Comment: @amWhy Well, then something must be wrong with these tags, since as it is described now any group theory (and not only!) question belong to abstract algebra.

Comment: @user I agree, wholeheartedly. It was Asaf who called me out on it. I think I'll continue adding it (and allow others to add it too), since I don't believe there is community consensus on the matter, and until the tag description changes (if it changes), I'll simply appeal to your logic, though I won't literally "point" to you. I'll just write out the tag description, as did you.